# Unit testing HttpStatusCode in MVC4 'System.NullReferenceException'

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-4, nunit, moq

I am trying to unit test HttpStatusCodes in MVC4 but I keep getting a 'System.NullReferenceException' when the controller tries to set the status code on Response, which makes sense as the action is getting called directly. I cant for the life of me work out how to do it without it becoming an integration test. Somebody must have done this, any ideas? See my existing code below.

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable;
    Response.Headers.Add("Retry-After", "120");

    return View();
}
```

**Test**

```
[Test]
public void IndexActionShouldReturn503StatusCode()
{
    //Given
    var controller = new HomeController();

    //When
    var result = controller.Index() as HttpStatusCodeResult;

    //Then
    result.StatusCode.Should().Be((int)HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable);
}
```

**Note**
The requirement is for a friendly 'site down' page so I need to return both a view and the status code.

Answer (score 2):

You're returning a `ViewResult`, then trying to cast it as a `HttpStatusCodeResult` in your unit test. Try returning a `HttpStatusCodeResult` instead of a view.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    Response.Headers.Add("Retry-After", "120");
    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable);
}
```

Comment: The purpose of the application is to serve a friendly 'site down' page that yields a 503, unless I'm mistaken (or missing something, which is probably more likely) by returning a HttpStatusCodeResult I can't serve my more friendly page?

Comment: @TomRiley You're correct. If you want to do that, you probably need to change your unit test to check the `Response.StatusCode`. But you'll probably need to mock the HttpContext so you have an object to unit test against (if you haven't already)